# Add-in not visible through Insert-->Web Part

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-addin

I have a classic SharePoint site hosted on SharePoint online.
I edit the Home Page and try to insert a Web Part but there isn't it listed!

[image]

In Visual Studio I have created a **SharePoint hosted** Add-in project, with all the logic that I want to be displayed to the user coded inside the `Default.aspx` page.

(I have read several times the [Microsoft example - Create add-in parts to install with your SharePoint Add-in](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-add-in-parts-to-install-with-your-sharepoint-add-in), but as it is related to Provider hosted add-in and I haven't been able to re-adapt it to my case).

In the Visual Studio solution I have added a `ClientWebPart` and I have pointed it to the Default.aspx page:

```
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ClientWebPart Name="VerbaliAddInPart" Title="VerbaliAddInPart" Description="VerbaliAddInPart Description" DefaultWidth="400" DefaultHeight="500">
    <Content Type="html" Src="~appWebUrl/Pages/Default.aspx?{StandardTokens}" />
    <Properties>
    </Properties>
  </ClientWebPart>
</Elements>
```

I think the problem could be that I have a wrong value for `Start Page` inside the `AppManifest.xml`.
(Actually it is the default value which is `VerbaliDiCollaudo/Pages/Default.aspx`).

How should I set the `Start Page` value?

Or maybe there isn't another problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using a dev site, You need to publish the app on an appcatalog.

Comment: Yes, good point, I missed to mention it. I have installed it on the app catalog, located at: `https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/apps/AppCatalog/`.  Then, in my site I have installed it: `Site contents-->Add an app` and _Trusted it_. After that I am able to launch it "directly" but I also would like to insert it inside my site Home Page.

Comment: Go to AppManifest, and change the startpage to DefaultPage.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have found how to solve the problem, but not the explanation!

If I point to the `Default.aspx` page, the Add-in is not displayed.

Default.aspx code is like this:

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

Instead if I add a new `AppPartContent.aspx` with code like this:

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<WebPartPages:AllowFraming ID="AllowFraming1" runat="server" />
<!-- Placeholder for edit mode message -->
<h1 id="editmodehdr" style="display:none">
    The app part is in edit mode.
</h1>
```

and make the Add-In `src` point to `AppPartContent.aspx` I can add it!

[image: Add-in is displayed in Edit page]

**Why can't I use `Default.aspx` page as my Add-in content?**